# Getting jobs list from Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to fetch/search jobs from the Linkedin API.
After creating an app, verifying it and getting an access-tokens (2-legged authorization)

- I'm able to get my data by sending GET requests to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me (with Authorization header)
- But

  - When I try:
    GET: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/recommendedJobs?q=byMember ([taken from official API page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/jobs/recommended-jobs)) I get the following: *"403: Not enough permissions to access: GET-byMember /recommendedJobs"*
  - And when I try

    1. GET : https://api.linkedin.com/v1/job-search (or https://api.linkedin.com/v1/jobs)
       I get: *This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs*
    2. GET : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/job-search (or https://api.linkedin.com/v2/jobs)
       i get *"Resource does not exist under v2"*

I've also tried logging using the Member Authorization (3-legged authorization), but nothing was better.

1. What's the API for getting jobs?
2. What type of authorization do I require?
3. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. With v2 the correct endpoint would be `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/recommendedJobs` https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/jobs/recommended-jobs#retrieve-recommended-job
2. You need `r_JYMBII` permission but that is not given to any app. You need to manually request that in behalf of your app in linkedin's developer admin panel.
3. First you tried using v2 API without the proper permission than you tried using v1 which is no longer available and than when you tried using v2 you used the old endpoint which doesn't exist under v2.

To be fair the v2 is a LOT more restrictive than v1 and from my experience it will take a lot of time to get permission from linkedin to use any permission apart from `r_liteprofile`, `r_emailaddress` and `w_member_social` that are the ones it gives by default to perform sign in and share.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: This page is removed some how.

Comment: Is there something similar available currently?